# Dying Light - Someone calling from atop an antenna during Pact with Rais

Tags: dying-light

As I was finishing the quest 'Pact with Rais' and going back to Rais' hideout, I heard a person calling me and saying he's on top of the antenna. He also asks if I can see him. Would like to know what side quest is this and where is he? I heard his voice as I was running along the pipes in the area marked below. This is the area which seems to always have a Toad or two and looks like a factory.

[image]

I can't seem to find him and the nearest antennas seems to be so far away that someone shouting from there couldn't possibly be heard.

Comment: Are you sure they're saying "Antenna?" Do you have subtitles on?

Comment: @Dallium Yes, I think that's what I heard. And no, that man's dialogue do not have subtitles . If I remember correctly, this was what he said: 'Hey, you. Can you see me? I'm at the top of the antenna. I need your help..' something along those lines. I'll try to go back later to see if I trigger the event again. I'm having a hard time since there's too many Virals and Toads in the area for me to look properly (I'm on hard mode).

Comment: IIRC there is some guy on top of a radio tower, less of an antenna.

Comment: @n_palum Oh, I apologize for the confusion but the game refers to them as antennas or antenna towers: http://dyinglight.wikia.com/wiki/Pact_With_Rais Although, yes, I think they can also be called that. What I think I heard, however, was antenna, not radio tower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After going through the list of side quests found on [game pressure](https://guides.gamepressure.com/) I believe I have found the sidequest.

I believe this to be the [Prodigal Son](https://guides.gamepressure.com/dyinglight/guide.asp?ID=29392) sidequest as it becomes available to you when completing 'The Pact With Rais', as well as the fact that Alexai (the one you need to speak to to trigger the quest) is found on an antenna tower and from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XYogpjfyuSI&feature=youtu.be) video the location seems to be quite near to your screenshot.

He is located at antenna 6a on the map. (apparantly)

Side note: I do not play the game so this answer is based on what I could find out online.

Comment: Seems like this is it. Thanks! Although I don't think this is available after the Pact with Rais because as I mentioned, that someone shouting at me occurred during the later part of the quest, not afterwards.

Comment: Ah. The prodigal son wiki says that "You can start this mission already when completing the Pact with Rais main quest" so that is why I made the assumption.

Comment: You are correct in saying that the wiki page says 'when completing' but this is different from 'after completing'. 'When completing', as stated in the wiki, implies that it can be done during the Pact of Rais. 'After completing', stated in your answer, implies that it is done afterwards :) Other than that, I found your answer helpful as I had a hard time trying to pinpoint where the guy shouting is.

Comment: Oh thanks. I'll add it to the answer so as to clear up any confusion :)